# Помогите сделать рулетку в c#

Tags: c#

Я сделал код но не могу сделать чтобы пока человек не ввел start то не начнется. У меня почему то он повторяется либо 1 либо 2 либо 3 раза подряд

```
using System;
namespace Program
{

    class Program 
    {
        static void Main() {
            Random rand = new Random();
            int ran = rand.Next(4);
            string[] nums = new string[3];
            nums[0] = "Машина <Lada Granta>";
            nums[1] = "10.000 рублей";
            nums[2] = "100 кристалов";
            Console.WriteLine("Введите start чтобы запустить рулетку!");
                if(Console.ReadLine() != "Start"){
                    while(Console.ReadLine() == "start"){
                        if(ran == 0){
                            Console.WriteLine(nums[0]);
                        } else if(ran == 1){
                            System.Console.WriteLine(nums[1]);
                        } else if(ran == 2){
                            System.Console.WriteLine(nums[2]);
                        } else {
                            System.Console.WriteLine("4");
                        }
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }    
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Ты проверяешь если человек не написал "Start" то твоя рулетка выполняется, должно быть наоборот
2. В методе Next ты указываешь число больше кол-ва элементов(4), элементов у тебя всего 3
3. Ну и много лишнего кода

---

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Xml;



namespace ConsoleApp
{
    using System;
    namespace Program
    {

        class Program
        {
            static void Main()
            {
                Random rand = new Random();
                string[] nums = new string[3];
                nums[0] = "Машина <Lada Granta>";
                nums[1] = "10.000 рублей";
                nums[2] = "100 кристалов";
                Console.WriteLine("Введите start чтобы запустить рулетку!");
                if(Console.ReadLine() == "Start")
                {
                   Console.WriteLine(nums[rand.Next(3)]);
                }
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Чтобы сделать выполнение бесконечным оберни это в такой цикл.

```
    using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Xml;



namespace ConsoleApp
{
    using System;
    namespace Program
    {

        class Program
        {
            static void Main()
            {
                Random rand = new Random();
                string[] nums = new string[3];
                nums[0] = "Машина <Lada Granta>";
                nums[1] = "10.000 рублей";
                nums[2] = "100 кристалов";
                while (true)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Введите start чтобы запустить рулетку!");
                    if (Console.ReadLine() == "Start")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(nums[rand.Next(3)]);
                    }
                }
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо!

Comment: @GeometryDahs вообще рекомендую тебе посмотреть SimpleCode, думаю там ты сможешь самостоятельно понимать где напортачил да и впринцыпе СимплКод затрагивает нужные основы, рассказывает интересно

Comment: Кстати сейчас запустил ток почему то он не останавливается когда написано start и выведан приз

Comment: @GeometryDahs там приведено 2 варианта. 1 там где выполняется 1 раз, 2 бесконечно

Comment: Я имею введу что типа он должен выполняться бесконечно раз пока человек не ввел start ^)

Comment: Значит убери ненужный код из цикла -_-

Comment: Просто понимаешь, за тебя такие мелочи делать не будут. По факту у тебя есть набор буковок, который ты сам отредактировать не можешь. Выше я уже сказал, что нужно сделать чтобы получить нужную базу в C#

Comment: Я понял, спасибо что подсказали - направили :)

Answer (score 0):

```
                if(Console.ReadLine() != "Start"){
                    while(Console.ReadLine() == "start"){
```

Тут у вас какая-то непонятная логика, в результате которой нужно минимум два раза что-то ввести, чтобы управление попало в остальной код. Насколько я понимаю, вам нужно так:

```
                while(Console.ReadLine() != "start")
                {
                }
                // тут остальной код
```